# The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047) - Visual Studio 2017

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, aspnet-compiler, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

I have ordinary ASP.NET project with .NET Framework 4.5.2, It work great as Web Site Projects (WSP), but I try to change this project to Web Application Projects (WAP). I don't change anything in body of project code, I only add designer with definition of control and add default namespace needed to WSP project. But aspnet_compiler crashed with message below (this is a part of MSBuild process):

> C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_compiler.exe -v /
>   -p E:\Projects\Arenda_5\MyArenda\ArendaNew\obj\Debug\AspnetCompileMerge\Source
>   -d E:\Projects\Arenda_5\MyArenda\ArendaNew\obj\Debug\AspnetCompileMerge\TempBuildDir
>   -errorstack
>
> Microsoft (R) ASP.NET Compilation Tool version 4.8.3752.0 Utility to
>   precompile an ASP.NET application Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.
>   All rights reserved. (0): warning : The following assembly has
>   dependencies on a version of the .NET Framework that is higher than
>   the target and might not load correctly during runtime causing a
>   failure: ArendaNew, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null. The dependencies are: Microsoft.VisualBasic,
>   Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.
>   You should either ensure that the dependent assembly is correct for
>   the target framework, or ensure that the target framework you are
>   addressing is that of the dependent assembly.
>
> E:\Projects\Arenda_5\MyArenda\ArendaNew\obj\Debug\AspnetCompileMerge\Source\global.asax(41):
>   warning BC42025: Access of shared member, constant member, enum member
>   or nested type through an instance; qualifying expression will not be
>   evaluated
>
> ....
>
> E:\Projects\Arenda_5\MyArenda\ArendaNew\obj\Debug\AspnetCompileMerge\Source\My_Saved.ashx(43):
>   warning BC42025: Access of shared member, constant member, enum member
>   or nested type through an instance; qualifying expression will not be
>   evaluated.
>
> error ASPPARSE: The given assembly name or codebase was invalid.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)
>
> error ASPPARSE: The given assembly name or codebase was invalid.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)
>
> error ASPPARSE: The given assembly name or codebase was invalid.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)
>
> error ASPPARSE: The given assembly name or codebase was invalid.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)
>
> error ASPPARSE: The given assembly name or codebase was invalid.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)
>
> error ASPPARSE: The given assembly name or codebase was invalid.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)
>
> [FileLoadException]: The given assembly name or codebase was invalid.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)    at
>   System.Reflection.AssemblyName.nInit(RuntimeAssembly& assembly,
>   Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean raiseResolveEvent)    at
>   System.Reflection.AssemblyName..ctor(String assemblyName)    at
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean throwOnFail)    at
>   System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.LoadAssembly(String assemblyName, Boolean
>   throwOnFail)    at
>   System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.AddAssemblyDependency(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean addDependentAssemblies)    at
>   System.Web.UI.MainTagNameToTypeMapper.ProcessTagNamespaceRegistrationCore(TagNamespaceRegisterEntry
>   nsRegisterEntry)    at
>   System.Web.UI.MainTagNameToTypeMapper.ProcessTagNamespaceRegistration(ArrayList
>   nsRegisterEntries)
>
> [HttpParseException]: The given assembly name or codebase was invalid.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)    at
>   System.Web.UI.MainTagNameToTypeMapper.ProcessTagNamespaceRegistration(ArrayList
>   nsRegisterEntries)    at
>   System.Web.UI.MainTagNameToTypeMapper.ProcessTagNamespaceRegistration(TagNamespaceRegisterEntry
>   nsRegisterEntry)    at
>   System.Web.UI.BaseTemplateParser.ProcessDirective(String
>   directiveName, IDictionary directive)    at
>   System.Web.UI.TemplateControlParser.ProcessDirective(String
>   directiveName, IDictionary directive)    at
>   System.Web.UI.PageParser.ProcessDirective(String directiveName,
>   IDictionary directive)    at
>   System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseStringInternal(String text, Encoding
>   fileEncoding)
>
> [HttpParseException]: The given assembly name or codebase was invalid.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)    at
>   System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseString(String text, VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, Encoding fileEncoding)    at
>   System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseReader(StreamReader reader,
>   VirtualPath virtualPath)    at
>   System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseFile(String physicalPath,
>   VirtualPath virtualPath)    at
>   System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseInternal()    at
>   System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.Parse()    at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BaseTemplateBuildProvider.get_CodeCompilerType()
>   at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider.GetCompilerTypeFromBuildProvider(BuildProvider
>   buildProvider)    at
>   System.Web.Compilation.WebDirectoryBatchCompiler.CompileNonDependentBuildProviders(ICollection
>   buildProviders)
>
> [HttpParseException]: The given assembly name or codebase was invalid.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)    at
>   System.Web.Compilation.WebDirectoryBatchCompiler.Process()    at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.BatchCompileWebDirectoryInternal(VirtualDirectory
>   vdir, Boolean ignoreErrors)    at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.BatchCompileWebDirectory(VirtualDirectory
>   vdir, VirtualPath virtualDir, Boolean ignoreErrors)    at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.PrecompileWebDirectoriesRecursive(VirtualDirectory
>   vdir, Boolean topLevel)    at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.PrecompileAppInternal(VirtualPath
>   startingVirtualDir, IEnumerable`1 excludedVirtualPaths)    at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.PrecompileApp(VirtualPath
>   startingVirtualDir, IEnumerable`1 excludedVirtualPaths)    at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.PrecompileApp(ClientBuildManagerCallback
>   callback, IEnumerable`1 excludedVirtualPaths)    at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManagerHost.PrecompileApp(ClientBuildManagerCallback
>   callback, List`1 excludedVirtualPaths)    at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManagerHost.PrecompileApp(ClientBuildManagerCallback
>   callback, List`1 excludedVirtualPaths)    at
>   System.Web.Compilation.ClientBuildManager.PrecompileApplication(ClientBuildManagerCallback
>   callback, Boolean forceCleanBuild)    at
>   System.Web.Compilation.ClientBuildManager.PrecompileApplication(ClientBuildManagerCallback
>   callback)    at System.Web.Compilation.Precompiler.Main(String[] args)

Comment: And finally I found a solution. The problem is low quality of Microsoft compiler code. If I would have name of wrong assembly i fix issue from a couple of seconds. But without a name of wrong assembly this is a job for three days. In my case I have definition of custom server control. This definition has become wrong from moving site from one structure (WSP) to another (WAP). And without name of wrong assembly and dozens assemblies of this project this became a challenge.